# What's the difference between 基建 and 基础设施? (Chinese words for "infrastructure")

Tags: translation

I've come across both these words recently and they seem to both translate to "infrastructure". Are they completely interchangeable or is there a difference in meaning? Or is it a question of regional usage or informal/formal language? Thanks in advance.

Comment: this depends on the degree of interchangeability desired, to facilitate answering question users are requested to include Chinese text in question itself, see dictionaries e.g. (below is only part of entries) bkrs： **基建** 1) capital construction
2) fine furniture or major appliance in a home 见“基本建设”e.g.   基建战线过长
overextension of capital construction  **基础设施** infrastructure; infrastructural facilities,, e.g. 基础设施应用程序支助科,Infrastructure Application Support Section,  基础设施 is the more general term, find many more examples at bkrs

Answer (score 1):

基建 is the short version or abbreviation of 基础建设。

Comment: or may be 基础设施建设

Answer (score 1):

基建 is the short version or abbreviation of Capital Construction ( **基本**建设), like log cabin construction or construction of sewer.

基础设施建设 means infrastructure, like hotels or transport.

> 基础设施建设，还没有简称，英语是Infrastructure 基础结构[设施](尤指社会、国家赖以生存和发展的, 如道路、学校、电厂、交通、通讯系统等),着重强调其“基础”的作用，和基本建设概念不同，是基建的，不一定是基础设施，比如建造俱乐部楼房（我个人理解）就不是一个城市赖以运转的基础设施了。